# vertical align not work when text mode is vertical-rl on firefox

Tags: html, css

I want align center vertical text in this table but it not work on Firefox.(it work fine on Chrome).

do you have idea to make it center on firefox?

```css
table{width: 100%;}
table td{border:solid 1px #333}
.ver td{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
vertical-align: middle;
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr> 
<tr class="ver"><td>this is a test</td><td>this is a test</td><td>this is a test</td></tr> 
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr> 
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`line-height`**:

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    table td {
        border:solid 1px #333
    }
    .ver td {
        --width: 400px; /*width of the item*/
        width: var(--width);
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: var(--width);
        padding:5px;
    }
```

Make sure the value is equal to the height of the element to vertically align the text centrally.

To explore further take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it work fine for one line text. but when I have two line text (wrapped text) it make issue. and in responsibility it not work fine.